# JavaFX launch inner Application class

Tags: java, javafx, inner-classes

I am trying to launch an inner Application class from the enclosing class, which does not work.

I already tried removing the static modifier from Window and launching it from an instance of Main.

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main {
    private static class Window extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            stage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(Window.class, args);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class VirtualLaunchpad$Window
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: VirtualLaunchpad$Window.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$7(LauncherImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application` subclass (and its no-arg constructor) must be public. The `Application.launch()` method only searches for public no-arg constructors when it instantiates the application class by reflection.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main {
    public static class Window extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            stage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(Window.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! :D I was absolutely sure I tried that! Thanks. Do you know if you can somehow get the Window instance from the Application.launch method or if you have to make the Window instance tell the Main class that is has just been launched?

Comment: @Kangalioo You can't get the instance of the `Application` class that is created by `launch()`, other than by referring to `this` in the `start()` (or `init()`) methods.

Comment: In my case class and constructor were public, but I was missing "static" keywork, therefore it wasn't starting.